# Python MQTT Receive how send the message?

Tags: python, windows, mqtt

Hello this my received of message on "STATE" , i have some clients to send the message on "STATE" .

The question is 'How can print the name of client to send the message;" on the below line of code.

```
print("received message: " ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))," from: ",str())
```

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("received message: " ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))," from: ",str())

mqttBroker ="localhost"

client = mqtt.Client("Smartphone")
client.connect(mqttBroker) 

client.loop_start()

client.subscribe("STATE")
client.on_message=on_message 

time.sleep(180)
client.loop_stop()
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it doesn't have this information who send message and client would have to send it inside message. But maybe you should use `dir(message)` to see if it sends something more.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You Don't

Longer answer:

MQTT messages do not contain any information about which client published the message unless you explicitly add it to the message payload.

The other option is to encode the sender information in the topic e.g. the clients publish to `STATE/client-id` and the subscribing client subscribes to `STATE/#` and then parses the `client-id` out of the topic provided to the `on_message` callback.

Comment: Thanks , is a good way to do it  i think . Is my first attach with this protocol and i try understand how  i can work.